# How to export a snapshot of the Index Field in PDF or JPG in Kofax Capture?

Tags: c#, export, kofax

I'm new at Kofax Capture. The question is how to export a snapshot of the Index Field in PDF or JPG in Kofax Capture? Like export signature from document.
The only thing comes into my mind is to code custom export module, but maybe I missed some features which are 'out of the box' or it would be great, if you provide some existing solutions.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can - Recognition scripts have access to zone snippets (small cutouts of an image that represent a zone being processed) and they can process the zone snippets in a custom engine (cf. Developer's Guide). Here's an example to get you started:

```cs
using Kofax.AscentCapture.NetScripting;
using Kofax.Capture.CaptureModule.InteropServices;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public class Save_Snippet : RecognitionScript {

    public Save_Snippet() : base()
    {
        this.BatchLoading += Save_Snippet_BatchLoading;
        this.BatchUnloading += Save_Snippet_BatchUnloading;
    }


    void Save_Snippet_BatchLoading(object sender, ref bool ImageFileRequired)
    {
        this.RecognitionPostProcessing += Save_Snippet_RecognitionPostProcessing;
        ImageFileRequired = true;
    }


    void Save_Snippet_BatchUnloading(object sender)
    {
        this.BatchLoading -= Save_Snippet_BatchLoading;
        this.RecognitionPostProcessing -= Save_Snippet_RecognitionPostProcessing;
        this.BatchUnloading -= Save_Snippet_BatchUnloading;

    }


    void Save_Snippet_RecognitionPostProcessing(object sender, PostRecognitionEventArgs e)
    {
        File.Copy(e.ImageFile, @"C:\temp\test.tiff");
    }

}
```

Comment: One more thing - if you need these snippets during export (in a custom export connector, of course), you could either save them to disk and store their location in an index field, or just store them as a base64 encoded image in said field.